# JFrame.dispose() to switch between JFrames to update a JList. Good or Bad Practice?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, dispose

everyone, so we have this GUI project at school, and it involves switching between two JFrames, and only one JFrame must be visible at a time.

So, my current implementation hides the previous frame when switching to the other frame, and vice versa. We use `frame.dispose()` when a button is clicked. It seems to do its job well, but as my classmate addressed, it may have some memory waste issues.

I've searched the net, some say it clears memory, but others say it just hides the frame, so basically that means that when i hide a jframe, its still there, and our program involves a lot of switching, so that would mean theres tens of "invisible frames" opened.

So if this is all true, what are other alternatives in switching between JFrames? 
**And no, removing the multiple JFrames part isn't an option.**

Edit: I forgot to mention, when switching frames, some of the information gets updated (It involves a JList). So I have to call the frame again to see the changes.

This is how I update the values (It's like a mini-database thing):

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Remove Contact");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                personToRemove=list.getSelectedValue().toString();
                dispose();
                Main.handler.remove(cstring);
                Main.main(args);
                }
        }
    });
```

so what the code does is call the frame again to show the new JList array (with the Contact removed). It isn't really switching but still the same concept. 

 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Couldn't you just use two frames, and call `setVisible` when you switch ? This way you won't have more frames creation than those two.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot to mention, when switching frames, some of the information gets updated (It involves a JList). So I have to call the frame again to see the changes.

Comment: Could you post your code, to see how you update the information ?

Comment: Hello, I updated the post, thanks for your reply!

Comment: Aren't you able to do as Berger suggested?

Comment: But if I just call setVisible(true), the info wont get updated, it shows the previous Jframe which had the outdated JList